# Can i copy data from one database table to another already existing database table sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, ssms

So i have 2 very similar databases, they are identical except for the data that exists in the tables. I want to copy the data from the EQUIP_MODEL table that exists in the PILOT database to the EQUIP_MODEL table that exists in the DOMAIN database.

Is this even possible? or do i have to do manual inserts for all the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fully qualified names in `Insert` statement

```
INSERT INTO DOMAIN.SCHEMANAME.EQUIP_MODEL (col1,col2,col3...)
SELECT col1,col2,col3.. FROM PILOT.SCHEMANAME.EQUIP_MODEL
```

To get the foreign key values (not the exact code you have to alter based on column name and mapping)

```
INSERT INTO DOMAIN.SCHEMANAME.EQUIP_MODEL
            (id,col2,col3)
SELECT sp.id,
       col2,
       col3
FROM   PILOT.SCHEMANAME.EQUIP_MODEL em
       JOIN PILOT.SCHEMANAME.Prent_table p
         ON em.id = p.id
       JOIN DOMAIN.SCHEMANAME.parent_table sp
         ON sp.somename_number_col = p.somename_number_col
```

Comment: I attempted this but i was getting the following error:

Comment: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FKEY9506". The conflict occurred in database "DAJCOR", table "dbo.EQUIP_TYPE", column 'id'.

Comment: @Azuraith - You may have to join the parent table and get the `id` of destination database

Comment: Ok that makes sense, so after joining the table in the FROM clause it ran the query and returned 0 row(s) affected. and then after doing

Comment: `SELECT * FROM DAJCOR.dbo.EQUIP_MODEL`

it had no data, sorry for posting in 2 comments accidently hit enter and edit comments is not available for some reason?

Comment: by sp.somename_number_col = p.somename_number_col what col would that be referring to?

Comment: @Azuraith - To get the `ID` from destination database. You need some other column to find the ID